# Any apex method equivalent to encodeURIComponent as that of JavaScript?

Tags: apex, javascript, controller, custom-button

We are replacing all the javascript buttons to custom VF buttons.
Have used encodeURIComponent methods in Javascript, unable to find the equivalent salesforce method

Have checked EncodingUtil Class in salesforce but that doesn't seem to solve the purpose ?

Input :

```
 var uri = "http://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
    var res = encodeURIComponent(uri);
```

Output :

```
http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab
```

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check:

```
String encoded = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(url, 'UTF-8');
```

Reference: [EncodingUtil](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm)

Example:

```
String url = 'http://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab';
String encoded = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(url, 'UTF-8');
System.debug(' Encoded URL: '+encoded);
```

Result:

> Encoded URL:
>   `http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy+test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab`